# What does it mean if a gallery-dl extractor (Instagram in this case) has two 'sleep-request' values in the JSON config file?

Tags: gallery-dl

In [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl), I understand that 'sleep-request' means the "minimal time interval in seconds between each HTTP request during data extraction" according to the [configuration description](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl/blob/master/docs/configuration.rst).

However, Instagram, for example, has two values for 'sleep-request' whereas the other extractors only have one value in the [default JSON configuration file:](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl/blob/master/docs/gallery-dl.conf)

```
  "instagram":
        {
            "api": "rest",
            "cookies": null,
            "include": "posts",
            "sleep-request": [6.0, 12.0],
            "videos": true
        },
```

What does having two 'sleep-request' values mean? What does the second value do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you've linked says this field is defined as a `Duration` type. Following that link to the [type definition](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl/blob/master/docs/configuration.rst#duration), you will find that it's a union type with 3 possibilities:

> A [`Duration`](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl/blob/master/docs/configuration.rst#duration) represents a span of time in seconds.
>
> - If given as a single `float`, it will be used as that exact value.
> - **If given as a `list` with 2 floating-point numbers `a` & `b` , it will be randomly chosen with uniform distribution such that `a <= N <= b`. (see random.uniform())**
> - If given as a `string`, it can either represent a single `float` value (`"2.85"`) or a range (`"1.5-3.0"`).